# How to include a css link in hidden input using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to include a CSS link in hidden input value using PHP. but it not including properly as shown in the image.

[image]

Code

```
<?php 
            $minCss='<link href="'.$bootstrap_js_link.'" rel="stylesheet">';

?>
 <input type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $minCss; ?>'" id="snippet_resource"/>
```

Comment: value="<?php echo $minCss; ?>" You don't need single quote

Comment: Getting this Now " id="snippet_resource"/>

Comment: You want a full `<link>` tag within the attribute? That's very odd, but look into `htmlspecialchars` then.

Comment: Why Someone giving this -ve instead of give answer!

Comment: because in your $minCss variable you have <link href="something" so you obtaine <input type="hidden" value="<link href="something"" rel="stylesheet"> id="snippet_resource"/>

Comment: @Jeto yes i want $minCss variable

Comment: Actually i am making a tool to show code snippets thats why i need to implement odd things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape HTML entities to include your value into the attribute. You may use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($minCss) ?>" id="snippet_resource" />
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me... someone voted this negative... is it silly question?

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan I think it was unclear why you were doing what you were doing. It probably seemed a rather unusual thing to do, sending that string as a form input. I can't say for sure, because I was not the downvoter.